# not work send email of gmail from codeigniter whit amazon ec2

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, gmail, config

this not work online in the amazon EC2 but in local work fine. And in the EC2 config security group view image:
[config EC2 security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTpdz.png)

My config controller is:

```
function SendEmail($Encabezado,$Nota){
    $ci = get_instance();
    $ci->load->library('email');
    $config['protocol']    = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
    $config['smtp_user'] = "mygmail@gmail.com"; 
    $config['smtp_pass'] = "mypass";
    $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
    $config['mailtype'] = "html";
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

    $ci->email->initialize($config);

    $ci->email->from('mygmail@gmail.com', 'blabla');
    $list = array('mymail@gmail.com');
    $ci->email->to($list);
    $this->email->reply_to('mygmail@gmail.com', 'Explendid Videos');
    $ci->email->subject($Encabezado);
    $ci->email->message($Nota);
    $ci->email->send();
}
```

waht is the problem? please help?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail SMTP port is just `smtp.gmail.com`

So, change this:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
```

To this:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

---

Try also to change in config EC2 security group SMTP port from 25 to 465, that is GMail default's port.

Comment: not work friend try this.  if not add the line $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl'; in local not work.